# Modify field data from a different app on Django

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

I have custom user models in an app called `users` on Django. code:

(users app)

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    classrooms = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    posts = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

(users app)

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser
admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

This all seems to work however I have a different app called `files` I need to modify the `posts` field in the `CustomUser` model from the `views.py` file in the `files` app. I think the answer to this has to do with foreign keys but for some reason I cannot wrap my head round them.

Comment: The CustomUser class should be in models.py and not views.py. You can create a Posts model and add ForeignKey to CustomUser class

Comment: @AAB Didn't mean to do that I just did that at 2:30 AM half asleep.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out what I had to do.
1). You most likely did this already but in your project's `settings.py` file go to the list called `INSTALLED_APPS` and add the app that has the custom model in my case that was `users` (I already did that step prior to asking)

2). Inside the `views.py` in the app that you want to modify it from add with your imports:

```
from users.models import CustomUser # Replace "CustomUser" with whatever the model is called in your case.
```

3). Then just reference it with `CustomUser` or whatever you called it.
so in my case:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```